# How to split one paragraph into sentences via tag in NLTK

Tags: python, regex, nltk

Now I have one paragraph after tagged, and I want to separate it into individual sentences in NLTK.

The first idea comes into my mind is to do that with `<PU>` tag, like `,` `.` punctuation like that. So the regular expression is as following:

```
    grammer = r"""
    NP:
        {<.*>+}
        }<PU>{
    """
```

However, I find I missing other punctuation like `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`...

So the above can not work well for the following sentence, because the punctuation `(` `)` is used to split into sentence.

`客户#NN 表示#VV 销售人员#NN 挺#AD 热情#VA 的#SP ，#PU 而且#AD 经销#VV 店里#NN 的#DEC 员工#NN 臧#NR 伟#NR (#PU 音#NN 同#CC )#PU 特别#JJ 热心#NN 。`

How can I split sentence only with `,` and `.` in Chinese?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just use a normal Python regex to split your paragraph:

```
import re
pat = re.compile('。|，')
paragraph = '客户#NN 表示#VV 销售人员#NN 挺#AD 热情#VA 的#SP ，#PU 而且#AD 经销#VV 店里#NN 的#DEC 员工#NN 臧#NR 伟#NR (#PU 音#NN 同#CC )#PU 特别#JJ 热心#NN'

pat.split(paragraph)
['客户#NN 表示#VV 销售人员#NN 挺#AD 热情#VA 的#SP ',
 '#PU 而且#AD 经销#VV 店里#NN 的#DEC 员工#NN 臧#NR 伟#NR (#PU 音#NN 同#CC )#PU 特别#JJ 热心#NN']
```